# Expo can I use Stream's React Native video call with Expo-Dev-Client?

Tags: react-native, expo, stream, videochat, expo-dev-client

I am making a mobile application using Expo Dev Client. I need to implement a video call functionality and I came across Stream, which looks like a great solution with React Native. However, will it work if I use it in Expo-Dev-Client? What would the changes to the code look like if it would?